# Any recomended Neural Network structure to classify similar images?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have a number of very similar images, and I want to classify them into two groups. I used Resnet50 before, but the network does not seem to be learning at all. As the training progresses, the validation accuracy always stays at around 50% to 60%. I have cropped the images to the most relevant portions and tried some other structures as well, but none of them seems to be working. Any suggestions or recommendations?

Comment: could you share some example for the classes of interest as it would help us better to give suggestions

Comment: Yes, the dataset consists of examples of human eyes, and I would like to classify them between short sightedness and long sightedness. @prashant0598

Comment: It is actually really hard to tell the differences, if there is any.